# Run a command with subprocess that has arguments as with & in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, subprocess

I am trying to run through subprocess a command line command that receives as arguments files. However, these files might have characters like "&" and those can be interpreted as CMD commands if they are not between quotes (").

It usually worked and I had the command passed broken in a list.
Example:

```
from subprocess import run
file = r'broken&difficult.txt'
command = ['convert', file]
run(command)
```

However it will return an stdErr:

```
StdErr: 'diffcult.txt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

The returncode is 1.

I have tried to change the file name variable to:

```
file =r'"broken&difficult.txt"'
```

The result is that it is not able to find any file. With a returncode of 0

Comment: Can you shows whats there in txt file?

Comment: im guessing here but did you try escaping it? `\&`

Comment: Is irrellevant what is in the txt file. The problem is that the & in the name breaks the command and the command line thinks that I am passing a new command. I have not tried to escape it, but I would try. The issue is that is coming from a bigger program where the user passes the files/folders to process. I don't have much control in the naming.

Comment: Try with a file name without `&` first, without and with enclosing `""`, just to make sure there is no path problem...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the CMD escape character - the carrot `^` - before the ampersand.

Try:

```py
import subprocess

file = 'broken^&difficult.txt'
command = ['convert', file]
subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
```

Example of how this works:

```py
import subprocess

# create a file
with open('broken&difficult.txt', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('hello\nworld')

# use `more` to have OS read contents
subprocess.run(['more', 'broken^&difficult.txt'], shell=True)

# prints:
hello
world
# returns:
CompletedProcess(args=['more', 'broken^&difficult.txt'], returncode=0)
```

Comment: It does not like neither. StdErr: 'difficult.txt' is not recognized and StdErr: & was unexpected at this time.

Comment: I left off the `shell=True` portion